# Vue.js - Using Child Components in a Single File Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue.js app. In this app, I have a [single file component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html). In this component, I want to have another component that's specific to the component. I'm trying to do something like this:

**parent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <child-component></child-component><br />
    <child-component></child-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        info: 'hello'
      }
    },

    components: {
      childComponent: {
        template: '<div>child</div>',
        data() { return {}; }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

After building with webpack, I then run my app in the browser. That app then generates an error in the console window that says:

*Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly?*

I believe I've set this up properly. However, clearly I haven't. What am I doing wrong? I can see where I may not have registered "child-component". However, I guess I'm not sure how to do that within a single file component. What am I missing?

Thank you,

Comment: hmm, works for me. Try `"child-component": {` instead of `childComponent: {`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas that might be helpful:
- as thanksd pointed out, register "child-component" intead of childComponent:

```
components: {
      "child-component": {
        template: '<div>child</div>',
        data() { return {}; }
      }
    }
```

- make sure you register the component before create the vue instance (this may or may not apply to your case, I cannot tell from the source code you posted:

  Vue.component(child-component', {
      template: 'child',
      data() { return {}; }
  })

  new Vue({ el: '#app' })